# Sonata Admin Bundle custom routes using annotations

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

So I work on a Sonata Admin custom app. I'm trying to create a custom action to download a file in a controller that extends CRUDController.

The action is:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/download-list/{id}", name="download_list")
     */
    public function downloadListAction($id = null) {
        $id = $this->get('request')->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());

        $object = $this->admin->getObject($id);

        if (!$object) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id : %s', $id));
        }
        if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('VIEW', $object)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $entity = $this->admin->getSubject();

        $exportFolder = $this->container->getParameter('export_folder');
        $filePath = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . $exportFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $entity->createListFileName() . $this->extension;

        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        return $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $entity->createListFileName());
    }
```

In `routing.yml` i have

```
spam_list_admin:
    resource: "@SpamAdminCoreBundle/Controller/SpamListAdminController.php"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /list
```

The router debugger shows my route, i can generate the uri using `$this->get('router')->generate('download_list', array('id' => $id))` but if I access it (app_dev.php/list/download-list/6) I get

```
There is no `_sonata_admin` defined for the controller `SpamAdmin\CoreBundle\Controller\SpamListAdminController` and the current route `download_list`.
```

This message is obviously crap, what is the real deal here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routes for Sonata CRUDController actions must be defined in your Admin class.

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    parent::configureRoutes($collection);
    $collection->add('download_list', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/download-list')
}
```

Comment: thank you. in the meantime i noticed that i need to configure the route "for symfony" to be able to create the uri using "$this->get('router')->generate" and also "for Sonata" to be able to access the page.